# Object Class's protected method MemberWiseClone()

Tags: c#, clone, protected

This might be a dumb question, but I don't get it:

I have a class called Card. I want to do a shallow clone using MemberWiseClone().
In Theory Card inherits from Object. So it should be able to use MemberWiseClone(), even if MWC() is protected ??

Am I missing/forgetting something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Card can use it.

```
class Card
{
   public Card Clone()
   {
      return (Card)MemberwiseClone();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only call a protected method on an object of the (compile-time) type of the class that your code is in.

Therefore, any particular class can only call `MemberwiseClone` on an instance of that class.
Since your class isn't `Card` (and doesn't inherit `Card`), you can't call `MemberwiseClone` on a `Card` instance.