# How do I use the MemberwiseClose() method in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, clone, derived-class

In a building-navigation program I am working on, my group uses a Room class made out of Tile objects. I want to find a way to data-bind the information of the room into an information bubble that pops up during a mouse enter event.

What I am attempting to do is through the MouseEventArgs e, use MemberwiseClone() to make a Tile object with the same information as the Tile that has the MouseEventHandler on it, and collect the information of the Room through that way.

However, since MemberwiseClone() is a protected method, I need to derive the MouseEventArgs class in order to use it in the class. However, since it is a WPF page, I'm not sure how to derive the other class.

What would be the best way to access the MemberwiseClone() method in this situation?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve but you can call it using `Reflection`

Comment: I doubt that it's actually necessary to create a copy of the original Tile instance, but how about having your Tile class implement the [IClonable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ICloneable.aspx) interface.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Looking at the Reflection page on MSDN, I do not see how it would help in this situation. Reflection returns the type of an object, and I don't see how that would help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel With reflection you van call _any_ method, no matter if it is `private`, `protected` or whatever. But it goes against the design of that class (they probably chose that access level for a reason), and it is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Some related threads, for reference: [Object Class's protected method MemberWiseClone()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914378/), and [How can i call MemberwiseClone()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066029/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're struggling to understand what `protected` means, here's a simple example:

```
class Tile
{
    internal static void Test(Tile t)
    {
        object mc = t.MemberwiseClone();  // works fine!
    }
}

class TypeFromWhichTileDoesNotDerive
{
    internal static void Test(Tile t)
    {
        object mc = t.MemberwiseClone();  // illegal, will not compile
    }
}
```

As you see, you can call the `protected` method (inherited from `System.Object`) on a `Tile` object `t` only if you are inside the `Tile` class (or inside some base class of `Tile`).

So if you want to take advantage of the `MemberwiseClone` method (be sure to understand what kind of clone it gives, a "shallow" clone), simply make a method *inside* the `Tile` class that calls `MemberwiseClone` on a `Tile`. Other code outside the `Tile` class can then call your method (depending on whether *your* method is `private`, `internal`, `protected`, `public`).

Comment: So, I would only be able to use the MemberwiesClone() method inside of the Tile class. This would mean trying to call the MemberwiseClone in the MainWindow class, where the constructing of maps takes place, is impossible?

Comment: @KarlThompson Did you see the last paragraph that I just added?

Comment: Just now, yes. Sorry for having to ask this, but what is a "shallow" clone?

Comment: @KarlThompson Shallow is the opposite of deep. Please read first the [doc page on the `MemberwiseClone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx). It all depends on what sort of non-static fields you have in your `Tile` class? What members does a `Tile` have that need to be cloned?

Comment: Since a shallow clone would not be helpful for what needed to be done, I managed to find a work-around. Thank you for your help, though.